# Flask Temperamental While Loading Basic Web Application

Tags: python, google-chrome, browser, flask, web-frameworks

I'm having trouble starting Flask for Python 2.7 via Eclipse & Chrome; it's so temperamental am having trouble clarifying the situations it works/doesn't:

Files are .project (Eclipse), **init**.py & pymongo1.py

```
from flask import Flask 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index page'

app.run(debug=True)
```

I load Eclipse, hit Run and get:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 5296)
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ...  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 2312)
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ...
```

which simply hands.  In Chrome, http://127.0.0.1:5000/ or 127.0.0.1:5000/ won't load anything.  Changing 'index page' to 'Index page' & hitting save gives

```
* Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Eddie\\Desktop\\dev\\health\\pymongo1.py', reloading
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 14:57:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
pydev debugger: Start reloading module: "pymongo1" ... 
pydev debugger: Start reloading module: "pymongo1" ...
```

..and keeps Chrome loading.  Hitting Run on Eclipse then gives:

```
pydev debugger: Start reloading module: "pymongo1" ... 
pydev debugger: Start reloading module: "pymongo1" ... 
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Eddie\\Desktop\\dev\\health\\pymongo1.py', reloading
pydev debugger: Start reloading module: "pymongo1" ... 
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Eddie\\Desktop\\dev\\health\\pymongo1.py', reloading
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 468, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356\pysrc\pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\Desktop\dev\health\pymongo1.py", line 115, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.7.egg\werkzeug\serving.py", line 623, in run_simple
    reloader_type)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.7.egg\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 229, in run_with_reloader
    reloader.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.7.egg\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 131, in run
    self.trigger_reload(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.7.egg\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 111, in trigger_reload
    sys.exit(3)
SystemExit: 3
ERROR: Module: pymongo1 could not be imported (file: C:\Users\Eddie\Desktop\dev\health\pymongo1.py).
```

Tried shutting down other apps in case they run on the same port, like Google Photos.  Any clues why it temperamentally loads content/seems to be getting stuck on the 'importing test module' part?  Regards

Comment: Why are you running it from Eclipse?  Run it from the command line.

Comment: Yes eclipse is most likely the issue here.

Comment: Amazing, many thanks @riotburn and Joe Doherty.  Started the .py file from Windows PowerShell, and can now make edits in Eclipse with things loading fine in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by @riotburn and @Joe Doherty.  The py file needed starting from Windows PowerShell.